# how to identify the special character in data file in java while reading in java?

Tags: java

how to identify the special character in data file in java while reading in java ?

Example: in below text file at line 5 after test5 having the enter character. ho can we know in java while reading the file.

```
12,test1,test2,test3,test4
13,test2,test2,test3,test4
14,test3,test2,test3,test4
15,test4,test2,test3,test4
16,test5
,test6,test7,test8
17,test4,test2,test3,test4
```

Comment: some input stream implementations provide a readLine() method so you can read line after line

Comment: by defining what you expect. In your example you expect a number followed by 4 strings all separated by comma(",") . You take this definition and parse element by element according to that definition(number, string, string, string, string); Now you can ignore whitespace, where it is neclectable(everywhere except before a new number ). So for the strings you expect either a whitespace followed by a string or a stringliteral. (string ::= whitespace string | stringliteral) or likewise according to your needs..  If you don't find what you expect, the file is malformed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using `BufferedReader.read()`. It reads the file character by character. So, we can check each character to see whether it is a "carriage return" (13), "new line" (10) etc.

In Windows, line break is normally "carriage return" + "new line".

(The file "data.txt" has the text you have mentioned in the question.)

```
import java.io.*;

public class ReadCharacters
{
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
  {
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("data.txt"));
    int i;
    int previousI = -1;
    while ((i = reader.read()) != -1)
    {
      if (i == 13)
      {
        System.out.println("Carriage return (\\r) character");
      }
      else if (i == 10)
      {
        System.out.println("New line (\\n) character");
        if (previousI == 13)
        {
          System.out.println("LINE BREAK (\\r\\n) FOUND!\n");
        }
      }
      else
      {
        System.out.println((char) i);
      }
      previousI = i;
    }
  }
}
```

Output is:

```
1
2
,
t
e
s
t
1
,
t
e
s
t
2
,
t
e
s
t
3
,
t
e
s
t
4
Carriage return (\r) character
New line (\n) character
LINE BREAK (\r\n) FOUND!

1
3
,
t
e
s
t
2
...
```